# AXIOS: First call to API returns the default state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, get, axios

I'm making a get request to a database to fetch some data. It always returns the default state (an empty object) first. Then it fetches the data as intended. How do I fix that?

```
export default function useEventIdSearch(id) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  const [event, setEvent] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    setError(false)
    let cancel
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://website.com/${id}?`,
      params: { api_key: 'dsfa' },
      cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
    }).then(res => {
      setEvent(res.data)
      setLoading(false)
      
    })
    .catch(e => {
      if (axios.isCancel(e)) return
      setError(true)
    })
    return () => cancel()
  }, [id])

  return { loading, error, event}
}
```

P.S. I'm a newbie so I apologize for my question since I guess it is a blunder from my side and has to do with asynchronous JS.

Comment: That's expected behaviour. You may want to return null instead and do a null check, or return an empty array, whichever is easier

Comment: As @NadiaChibrikova mentioned. React first does initial render with initial values, then it executes your ajax request to retrieve data.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova so do I have to set the event state to a null? And what place in my code should I do that null check? Or the null check has to be in a component that renders this data? Sorry, I am confused a bit.

Comment: Yes, you set `event` to `null` and whatever is calling the function will do the check. You can render some sort of placeholder while fetching the data, like `{event == null ? <div>Loading</div> : (something more useful here)}` Or you can use your `loading` flag for that.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova thank you! It works now.

Comment: Glad it helped!